# Can I know with JavaScript if the device orientation is locked?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

Most likely it's not possible, but I'd like to try all possible ways before abandoning it.

Is it possible in browser to know if the screen orientation is locked in settings?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a way to read it from the device settings through a JS API. There is a [Screen Orientation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation) but it doesn't seem to have that specific property.